# document.createElement multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

I was reading through the *polymer* documentation, and I saw this:

`var el2 = document.createElement('input', 'my-input');` [Source](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html)

Forgetting about *polymer* for a second, can `document.createElement` currently take 2 arguments? Is it related to Polymer's type-extensions?

Side note:
[Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) was "complaining" when I called it with 2 arguments.

Comment: Looking at the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) it does not appear that this function takes in two arguments, so it would ignore the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, `document.createElement` will only take one parameter (Ignoring the second). It does appear that there is a spec that will allow you to pass a `typeExtension` which you can read about [here](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#extensions-to-document-interface-to-instantiate). <strike>This spec is still in the works, and is not implemented in any form on any browser as of yet.</strike>

Quick edit: It does appear that chrome stable does contain the `typeExtension` parameter, which can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/dom/Document.idl&q=createelement%20idl&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=191). Thanks @ScottMiles for the clarification.

Comment: It's implemented in Chrome stable.

Comment: Do you have any docs anywhere @ScottMiles? I couldn't find anything anywhere, other than it's a spec that's still under review.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/dom/Document.idl&q=createelement%20idl&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=191

Answer (score -2):

No it can not. FROM MDN: In an HTML document, the Document.createElement() method creates the specified HTML element or an HTMLUnknownElement if the given element name isn't a known one.

```
var element = document.createElement(tagName);
```

element is the created Element object.
tagName is a string that specifies the type of element to be created. The nodeName of the created element is initialized with the value of tagName.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement