# Document.createElement arity

Tags: javascript, dom

This is related to but not exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767350/document-createelement-multiple-arguments) question. I recently had some code that broke on several browsers because it wrapped `document.createElement` with a decorator that curried the built-in function.

Opening up the chrome console and typing `document.createElement.length` yields 1, in FF/Safari, 2.

Why? Is it the optional type extension in mentioned in the other question (which oddly enough is a chrom(ium) thing for webcomponents' custom elements)? What does the standard say about this?

#### UPDATE

It is indeed (at least in FF) related to the typeExtension, `document.createElement.toString()` in the console returns

```
function createElement(tag, typeExtension) {
    if (tag) {
      tag = tag.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (typeExtension) {
      typeExtension = typeExtension.toLowerCase();
    }
    var definition = getRegisteredDefinition(typeExtension || tag);
    if (definition) {
      if (tag == definition.tag && typeExtension == definition.is) {
        return new definition.ctor();
      }
      if (!typeExtension && !definition.is) {
        return new definition.ctor();
      }
    }
    var element;
    if (typeExtension) {
      element = createElement(tag);
      element.setAttribute("is", typeExtension);
      return element;
    }
    element = domCreateElement(tag);
    if (tag.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
      implementPrototype(element, HTMLElement);
    }
    return element;
  }
```

##UPDATE 2
[github issue](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/523) - see Jeremy's answer.

Comment: Chrome's console returns `1`? That's pretty funny, because I believe it's the only implementation of `document.createElement` which actually does accept two arguments (for their implementation of Web Components)! The standardized specs don't include this yet, because it's not entirely settled, but they'll be patched quite soo to accept two arguments. (Though more generally, I'd use `arguments` if possible to avoid hard-coding the number of arguments.)

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get 1 both on FF and Chrome, and 0 on IE/Edge. Usually optional parameters are not counted anyway.

Comment: @Oriol FF 45.0, linux mint

Comment: @JaredSmith No repo on FF 45 Ubuntu. Are you perhaps testing on a page that modifies the definition?

Comment: So now that you have updated the question, .... what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code you've quoted [is from the Polymer team's Web Components polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/4d3355f436d2bad188ac7d8609fac9e8b0cb466b/src/CustomElements/register.js#L276), not the native browser implementation. If you try it in a page that doesn't include the polyfill, you'll get different results (Firefox on Ubuntu):

```
> document.createElement.length
1

> document.createElement.toString()
"function createElement() {
    [native code]
}"
```

The reason you get `1` in Chrome is because it currently includes a native implementation of Web Components (which still has `.length` of 1), so the polyfill isn't being used.

The built-in function doesn't yet have `.length` of 2 in any browsers. However, the specification of `createElement` is going to change soon, so don't rely on this remaining true.

Comment: I was just about to answer with that myself. I'll file an issue on github with the polyfill.

Comment: @Oriol and safari. Chrome gives 1 though.

Comment: @JaredSmith What do you consider the polyfill to be doing wrong? The mismatch in `.length` between it and Chrome's native implementation? (I don't know what the correct behaviour is here; I've never used function.length.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks function.length is the number of formal parameters. If you are currying a function you can use it to tell the curry function when the argument function has received enough parameters to be applied. Problem here is I'm getting back the curried function waiting on the second param instead of a DOM node.